# How to modify a field in a nested pymongo dictionary record in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested, pymongo-3.x

I have a mongo db with following structure

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f59c289fb28ab4476d4578b"),
"data" : [ 
    {
        "time" : "10-Sep-2020 11:33:22",
        "type" : "Med01",
        "id":123
        "expdate" : "01-Sep-2021",
        "in_stock" "Y"

    }, 
    {
        "time" : "10-Sep-2020 11:33:22",
        "type" : "Med06",
        "id":125
        "expdate" : "10-Sep-2020",
        "in_stock" "N"

    },
    {
        "time" : "10-Sep-2020 11:33:22",
        "type" : "LOC1",
        "id":103
        "expdate" : "10-Sep-2023",
        "in_stock" "Y"

    }
]
```

}

I would like to update the `in_stock` field based on the given `id`, say for example I need to modify the `in_stock` of medicine with `id` `103` to `N`

I tried with below and it is working but I won't be knowing the list number (`2`) in advance.

```
update_one({"_id": id_1}, {'$set': {"data.2.in_stock":'N'}})
```

I have the value `2` in a variable but not sure how to pass that in the above query. Can someone  help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `$` [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_). Note this will match on the first matching array element only.

```
db.mycollection.update_one({'_id': id_1, 'data.id': 103}, {'$set': {"data.$.in_stock":'N'}})
```